# Looping through the PromptDialog.Choice dialog (Bot Framework)

Tags: c#, botframework

I have tried to create a `PromptDialog.Choice` when the attempts reaches the given count it is giving a predefined an error like:

> too many attempts

And I have implemented the call back function in a try catch but the debug is not hitting the catch part so that I can loop again.

Calling Function

```
PromptDialog.Choice(context,
            PromptOperations, new string[] { "Add", "Subtract", "Multiply", "Division" },
            $"Hey " + name + "\n\n Select what do you want to perform today ?",
            "Didn't get that", 3,
            PromptStyle.Keyboard);
```

Call back function

```
private async Task PromptOperations(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> result)
        {
            try
            {
                //Some Operations
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Exceeded Attempts Loop Again
                PromptDialog.Choice(context,
                PromptOperations, new string[] { "Add", "Subtract", "Multiply", "Division" },
                "Please select valid option",
                "Didn't get that", 3,
                PromptStyle.Keyboard);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing an `await result` on the `try` part to force it to go the `catch` part.

```
try
{
   var selection = await result;
   // some operations
}
```

Comment: Hey @Ezequiel Jadib , Thanks it worked...  Can you suggest me some good tutorials to learn Bot framework in deeper(With good examples). Thanks in advance